# Каковы падежи числительного четыреста?

Tags: числительные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В количественных числительных при склонении меняются все корни всех слов.
Если в составе есть  сотни - корень -сот-,  при затруднении подставляем вместо слова СОТ – НОТА:

И.В.  – четыреста

Р.     Четырёх нот – четырёхсот

Д.     Четырём нотам – четырёмстам

Т.     Четырьмя нотами – четырьмястами

П.   О четырёх нотах – о четырёхстах